# i want to check a manufacturer already exists or not by clicking the submit button,i am doing this in codeigniter,

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to check if  a manufacturere in the database already exists and if it does not then insert them.

I have tried to do a where statement that checks if their is manufacturer exists in the database but even if their are new information it does not insert it into the database

Im quite lost here any guidance would be appreciated

```
              controller
                function manufacturertable($user)
                            {


                                     $m1=$this->input->post('man');
                    //            
                    $result['query']=$this->erp_m->insertmanu($m1,$user);
                    //                   


                            }

            model
            function insertmanu($m1,$user)

     1. List item

            {


                $this->db->where('manufacture',$m1);
               $query=$this->db->get('manufacturer3');

               foreach($query->result() as $row)



                  $x=$row->manufacture;

            if($x==$m1)
            {

             echo"already exists";

            }
            else
            {
            $data = array('manufacture'=>$m1,'user'=>$user);

              $this->db->insert('manufacturer3', $data);      

            }
            }


            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change model function as following.

```
      function insertmanu($m1,$user)
      {
           $this->db->where('manufacture',$m1);
           $res=$this->db->get('manufacturer3');
            $num=$res->num_rows();
           if($num>0)
          {
          return "already exist";
          }
          else
          {
           return "not exist";
          }
      }
```

and then use return string to echo on browser in controller.

Comment: sir i cant echo it in controller please help,how to use this return string it in controller, i m new to codeigniter

Comment: make change in your controller like 
                   echo $result['query']=$this->erp_m->insertmanu($m1,$user);